# Nginx - Access Http custom headers

Tags: nginx, netscaler

I have a simple requirement. I have a nginx web server and a netscaler proxy. From netscaler, the option Client_IP header is checked, and name of header is HTTP_CLIENT_IP.

I want to access this ip in nginx log. I have specified a custom log format, so i can access this value:

I have tried the following variables in the log format, and they just return in '-'.

```
$http_client_ip
$http_request_body
```

Basically, i want to read the entire request header / body that nginx receives from netscaler.

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: How exactly netscaler sends client's IP to nginx!

Comment: @AlexeyTen, it can be configured to send the client's IP as the source IP. If not configured, the NetScaler VIP is passed as the client IP.

Answer (score 0):

Netscaler inserts a http header with the client ip, if enabled. However You have to configure the http header name on the netscaler.