# Nginx - Access Http custom headers v2

Tags: http, nginx, http-headers

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307443/nginx-access-http-custom-headers) and [this question,](https://serverfault.com/questions/636790/nginx-log-complete-request-response-with-all-headers) I have a client (bazel) that is sending requests to nginx.

The client is adding a custom header called `build_id` as `HTTP_BUILD_ID` to each request.

**I just want to log this header from `nginx`.**

I wrote a small python `flask` application and printed all the headers and it showed that `HTTP_BUILD_ID` is indeed part of the request.

Unfortunately, `nginx` can't find it. This is what my log_format looks like with the addition of `$http_build_id`.

```py
log_format main '$remote_addr - $upstream_cache_status [$time_local]
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '[$http_build_id]'
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending it as `HTTP_BUILD_ID`, then you should use `"$http_http_build_id"` in your log_format

Also, do check your virtual host (server) definition to make sure it's using the `main` format. Some default installs look like: `access_log FILE combined`, where `combined` is a predefined format. Read more about that [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)

As pointed by the OP, installing the [nginx-echo-headers](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/nginx-echo-headers) package pointed out to some invalid headers. Adding `underscores_in_headers on;` fixed the issue.

Comment: The header HTTP_USER_AGENT is shown as $http_user_agent.
While HTTP_REFERER is seen as $http_referer.

I assumed that HTTP_BUILD_ID would be seen as $http_build_id.

Comment: Look at `x-forwarded-for`. To log it, it's `http_x_forwarded_for`. User-Agent, Referrer, these are not prefixed by HTTP when sent by the browser. In nginx, to get a header, you do `http_HEADER`. And in your case, because your header is `HTTP_BUILD_ID`,  you have the double http

Comment: Your answer is semi correct. I used `$http_build_id` but I needed to fix some configuration. Please update your answer.

I used https://github.com/brndnmtthws/nginx-echo-headers to echo out what my requests were and then realized that it was saying that my header was invalid. I then added `underscores_in_headers on;` to fix the issue.

Comment: @GGhe, thanks, updated. I will do a re-test on my end with that. Thanks for digging in more about this!